# Calling table.sort returns nil

Tags: lua

I am trying to sort a table 'array' that contains tables with two keys called 'pt' and 'angle'. I want to sort the 'array' elements regarding their 'angle' value. To my understanding of table.sort this code snippet should do the trick:

```
local array = {}

-- Some code that calls 
-- table.insert(array, {pt = somePt, angle = someAngle})
-- multiple times

local sorted_table = table.sort(array, function(a,b) return a.angle < b.angle end)
```

However, sorted_table is always nil. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table.sort` sorts the array part of a table in place.  It does not return a new array.  If you need to keep the original, you first need to copy to a temporary array.

So, try something like this:

```
table.sort(array,function(a,b) return a.angle < b.angle end)
```

Comment: Except it doesn't. The array part doesn't have much to do with how many items get sorted. It's both possible that the array part isn't completely filled or that you have consecutive numerical indices that go beyond the end of the array part.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Arrays don't have 'holes'.  If there are holes, it's not an array. The way I understand https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html, `table.sort` is supposed to sort arrays, not tables in general. Also from https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html: "When you iterate over the elements of the array, the first non-initialized index will result in nil; you can use this value as a sentinel to represent the end of the array".  How `table.sort` affects the internal ordering of the table is irrelevant as the sorting only makes sense for arrays (i.e., 1..N). With holes, `table.sort` fails

Comment: "Array part" is the terminology used in the implementation documentation; It's meaning there is not relevant. Sorting only makes sense for the [sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) of a table that has an empty or non-empty sequence. Calling a table's sequence an "array part" or an "array" or both is confusing. @SuperTasche, generally, for each table, you would choose to either use _and maintain_ a sequence or not.

Answer (score 3):

`table.sort` sorts the table in place; that is, it changes the table that you give it and doesn't return a new one.

If you want a sorted copy, you'd first have to make a copy of the table yourself, then sort it.

This could look like this:

```
local function sorted_copy(tab, func)
  local tab = {table.unpack(tab)}
  table.sort(tab, func)
  return tab
end
```

That will create a copy of the table (at least the numeric indices up to some random border) and sort it.

Comment: thanks for the code - i changed the first line to `table.sorted = function(tab, func)` - now i can use instead of `table.sort` this line `newtable = table.sorted(` - interesting when i like to have one liners in the Hammerspoon console ;) for example `hs.inspect(table.sorted(myTable))`

Answer (score 0):

there is no secret, there is an algorithm for this sorting, which has been used many times:

```
function quicksort(t, sortname, start, endi)
  start, endi = start or 1, endi or #t
  sortname = sortname or 1
  if(endi - start < 1) then return t end
  local pivot = start
  for i = start + 1, endi do
    if  t[i][sortname] <= t[pivot][sortname] then
      local temp = t[pivot + 1]
      t[pivot + 1] = t[pivot]
      if(i == pivot + 1) then
        t[pivot] = temp
      else
        t[pivot] = t[i]
        t[i] = temp
      end
      pivot = pivot + 1
    end
  end
  t = quicksort(t, sortname, start, pivot - 1)
  return quicksort(t, sortname, pivot + 1, endi)
end


local array = {}

table.insert(array, {pt = 1, angle = 2})
table.insert(array, {pt = 4, angle = 9})
table.insert(array, {pt = 1, angle = 5})
table.insert(array, {pt = 2, angle = 7})
table.insert(array, {pt = 2, angle = 1})
table.insert(array, {pt = 5, angle = 2})

local s_t = quicksort(array, "angle")


for k,v in pairs(s_t) do
        print(k, "v=", v.pt, v.angle)
end
```

Output:

```
1   v=  2   1
2   v=  5   2
3   v=  1   2
4   v=  1   5
5   v=  2   7
6   v=  4   9
```